# Configure reverse proxy apache on centOS 7 not fond

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I am configuring apache for reverse proxy and when executing it I cannot reach the destination IP

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    #ProxyPass "/guirao/api/" "http://IP/guirao/"
    <Location /acerbis/api>
       ProxyPass http://IP/acerbis/
       ProxyPassReverse http://IP/acerbis/
    </Location>
    #ProxyPass "/skumanic/api/" "http://IP/skumanic/"
    #ProxyPass "/ocana/api/" "http://IP/ocana/"
    #ProxyPass "/impress/api/" "http://IP/impress/"
    #ProxyPass "/maxibici/api/" "http://IP/maxibici/"
    #ProxyPass "/faz/api/" "http://IP/faz/"
    #ProxyPass "/kevin/api/" "http://IP/kevin/"

    #ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you reach destination IP when you test with curl (from apache server's terminal)?

Comment: Yes, I arrive without problems

Comment: What error exactly do you see when you try to access through apache?

Comment: I do not throw error, I do not reach the redirection directly

Comment: If `http://IP/acerbis/` ends with sash, then `/acerbis/api` should end with slash.

Comment: I changed it, but it doesn't work: <Location /acerbis/api/>